# Laravel return wrong column name of database to save data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

in Laravel migration i have this line :

```
$table->tinyInteger('action_type')->index();
```

and when i try to save data in the table like with this code:

```
ActionsLog::create([
    'account_id' => auth()->user()->id,
    'action_type' => 1,  //like
    'log', $ex->getMessage()
]);
```

laravel couldn't return third column which that name is `action_type` and i get this error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `actions_logs` (`account_id`, `action_type`, `1`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, 1, SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `actions_logs` (`account_id`, `action_type`, `1`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, 1, Use of undefined constant ture - assumed 'ture' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP), 2018-07-11 07:50:18, 2018-07-11 07:50:18)), 2018-07-11 07:50:18, 2018-07-11 07:50:18))
```

My migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('actions_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('instagram_actions_histories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->tinyInteger('action_type')->index();
        $table->text('log');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is with line `'log', $ex->getMessage()`. Change `,` in this line to `=>`.  Replace code as:

```
ActionsLog::create([
    'account_id' => auth()->user()->id,
    'action_type' => 1,
    'log' => $ex->getMessage()
]);
```

Comment: 'log' => $ex->getMessage() ------- 'log', $ex->getMessage(). In first key => value, in second value, value

Answer (score 0):

you sholud create like that

```
ActionsLog::create([
'account_id' => auth()->user()->id,
'action_type' => 1,
'log'=> $ex->getMessage()
]);
```